# How do I throw an error based on conditions in googlescript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to check if a cell has a value and if it does, I have a function that works, if the cell has no value, I want the function to have a status of 'Failed'.

I added else new Error('No data to import'), but My Executions still show status of 'Completed'

A2 is a formula that imports data from a table on a website, it doesn't always work and if it doesn't work, don want it to overwrite the information last pulled. I also want to know when it doesn't work so that I can look into it.

`if(dataDump.getRange('A3').getValue()){
    dataDump.getRange('A2:A5200').copyTo(allInvoices.getRange('A2:A520'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);}
   else new Error('No data to import'); }`

if 'A3' has a value, take the new data and replace the old, if 'A3' is blank, don't overwrite the old data, also, let me know that it failed.

Comment: I'm super thankful the issue got solved, but keen to hear why the question would be downvoted, I did spend a lot of time trying to find the answer before I asked. I know its a dumb question given how simple the answer is, but I tried to google it a bunch of different ways and couldnt find the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) the [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), that you just created.

```
 else throw new Error('No data to import');
```